# Xcode 12 and Apple Silicon

Tags: xcode, apple-silicon

Will the new Xcode 12 support making apps for computers that do not run on the new Apple Silicon?
I would like to know this because I need to make a new app for myself.

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For such conformations/News please prefer to make a quick google search.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates specifically to support for a commercial product. These types of questions are not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more info.

Comment: Yes, You can build the universal binary using XCode 12 Beta 3

Answer (score -1):

simpler response: YES. pls read apple docs.